# my loop starts from number 1 instead of 2

Tags: abap

This is my first time in ABAP.

---

```
DATA: n(1) TYPE I VALUE '2',
      sum(2) TYPE I.

DEFINE multiple.
   WHILE sy-index < 10.
     sum = &1 * sy-index.
     WRITE: / &1, 'x', sy-index,  sum.
   ENDWHILE.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

DO 9 TIMES.
   IF sy-index = 1.
     CONTINUE.
   ENDIF.

   multiple sy-index.
ENDDO.
```

---

so, below the output produced by my program.

```
1 x 1    1
2 x 2    4
3 x 3    9
```

---

The actual result is not what I am expecting.

---

The expected result should be...

```
2 x 1  2
2 x 2  4
2 x 3  6
2 x 4  8
2 x 5  10

..
..
..
```

Comment: http://www.saphub.com/abap-tutorial/loops/

tell this site...  'sy-index is a system variable.'

Comment: i'm not sure what '&1' does in abap. Why don't you multiply sy-index with your declared variable 'n'?

Comment: Using a macro in this case is definitely _not_ a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please do not operate on a global variable inside a form, macro, method or function module. Pass it as a parameter.

Second of all, here is some solution to your problem.

I also left the `multiple` functionality as macro but it should rather be implemented as at least a `FORM`.

```
DATA: sum(2) TYPE i.
DATA: l_outer_loop_index TYPE i.

DEFINE multiple.
  sum = &1 * &2.
  WRITE: / &1, 'x', &2,  sum.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

DO 9 TIMES.
   IF sy-index = 1.
     CONTINUE.
   ENDIF.
   l_outer_loop_index = sy-index.
   DO 9 TIMES.
     multiple l_outer_loop_index sy-index.
   ENDDO.
ENDDO.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank Jagger,I reference his answer.I have a litter change. This is my first answer.I hope this can help you.

```
DATA: sum(2) TYPE i.
DATA: sumstring(2) TYPE c.
DATA: l_outer_loop_index TYPE i.
DATA: result(100) TYPE c.
DATA: num1(10) TYPE c,
      num2(10) TYPE c.
DEFINE multiple.
  clear: result.
  sum = &1 * &2.
  WRITE &1 to num1.
  WRITE &2 to num2.
  WRITE sum to sumstring.
  CONDENSE sumstring.
  CONDENSE num1.
  CONDENSE num2.
  concatenate  num1 'x' num2 '=' sumstring INTO result SEPARATED BY space.
  WRITE: / result.
END-OF-DEFINITION.
DO 9 TIMES.
  IF sy-index = 1.
    CONTINUE.
  ENDIF.
  l_outer_loop_index = sy-index.
  DO l_outer_loop_index TIMES.
    multiple l_outer_loop_index sy-index.
    IF l_outer_loop_index = sy-index.
       WRITE: / .
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.
ENDDO.
```

Answer (score -1):

TRY my solution

```
DATA: n(1)   TYPE i VALUE '2',
      sum(2) TYPE i.


DO 9 TIMES.
   IF sy-index = 1.
     CONTINUE.
   ENDIF.

   PERFORM multi using sy-index.
ENDDO.

FORM multi USING i_num TYPE i.
  DATA: lv_num TYPE i.

  MOVE i_num TO lv_num.
     DO 10 TIMES.
      IF sy-index = 1.
        CONTINUE.
      ENDIF.
     sum = lv_num * sy-index.

     WRITE: / lv_num, 'x', sy-index,  sum.

   ENDDO.
ENDFORM.
```